# Saving data that is displayed by using ViewBag, to database

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a controller class and a method inside the controller as below:

```
public class MaskController : Controller
{
    private void PopulateWork()
    {
       ViewBag.WorkInfo = "This is Work 1";
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      PopulateWork();
      return View();
    }
}
```

I am then using ViewBag's WorkInfo in my Index.cshtml to display the information contained by WorkInfo as below:

```
 @Html.Display("WorkInfo")
```

The output is: `"This is Work 1"` is displayed.

I now want to save the displayed information (output) to my database using EF. I am also using bootstrap. Is there a way to do that - to save the displayed info to my database.

I tried using `Html.DisplayFor()`, but that's not working. Please suggest a way!

Thanks!